# C# / ASP.NET alternative to a PERL .pl IIS hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net, perl, iis

I am porting a PERL (.pl file) which is a socket listener, which is hosted on IIS web server. A PERL client just opens a socket connection to this PERL server and start transferring data.

What ASP.NET technologies (without webpage and webservice) is the equivalent of this PERL service. Is there a ASP.NET web template that is ideal to just add the websocket C# code  and have it always up and listening to a port for incoming traffic and be hosted on the IIS (Just like the PERL file and its simplicity. I am not looking for WCF answer. And how would it be configured on the IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few options here, if the socket is HTTP based then you could have a peek at [Custom Handlers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001), these transfer everythign through HTTP though. If you are looking for just a socket which doesn't handle HTTP then you're probably not going to want to do that in IIS/ASP.NET but rather a C# Service, have a peek at a [C# tutorial for multithreaded services](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server). [You can easily port this code into a service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

The problem is that IIS is really designed to be a HTTP/HTTPS protocol so your trying to force it to do things it wasn't designed for, you could go down the route of custom ISAPI modules, and HTTP modules but again you'd be trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.